# Java values not adding together

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it so I retrieve the value of a text field, and when I select a checkbox, it will add the value of `a1` to the value of the text field.

For example, the textfield = 12

a1 = 35

I want it to add to 47 but it just updates to 35. This is what I have so far

```
if(mon.isSelected()) {
pear.setText(String.valueOf(+a1));
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try `pear.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(pear.getText())+a1));`
Essentially, you are setting the value to a1 instead of adding it to the original value.

Comment: To clarify: You need `Integer.parseInt()` so that it actually adds the numbers to `47` and does not concatenate them as strings to `"1235"`.

Comment: To further clarify what went wrong: The `+` in the expression `+a1` is an unary positive sign operator, not a binary addition operator. E.g. compare `-b` to `a - b`. The first is a negate of the value of `b`, and the second is subtraction of `b` from `a`. Similarly for `+b` vs. `a + b`.

Comment: Okay, thanks this works but I have a new problem. I have more code that is exactly like my post but with `a2`. `a2` being a different number and being applied when something other than `mon` is selected. When I apply it, it just errors with `"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"` with several other lines. How can I avoid this?